# Allennlp coref model latest version

Tags: allennlp

I'm searching for the latest tar file of coref model of allennlp. where can i find it.

Because in demo page of allennlp that output is different and when i tried using the example code the output is different.
The version in the example was 2018-05-02.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you are looking for the model link

https://allennlp.s3.amazonaws.com/models/coref-model-2018.02.05.tar.gz

here is the [list of models](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-hub/blob/master/allennlp_hub/pretrained/allennlp_pretrained.py) with download links(Make sure to change the date of the model to get the earlier versions).

Please mark the answer as accepted if useful.